# How to fix "EOF error when reading a line"

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am attempting to write a basic program on my text editor (TextWrangler). I keep getting an `EOF error` no matter what I do. Here is my code:

```
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?') # ask for their age
myAge = input()
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

The error I get is for line 3:

> "EOF error: error when reading a line".

I have tried both `raw_input` and `input()`, nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I think wherever it is you are running this, it does not support input. I've seen this happen using SublimeText. If you are using SublimeText, install SublimeREPL. That would solve this problem.

Comment: Line 5 in your code does not contain `input` . Please post the actual code the actual error message, with full traceback.

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 3! My apologies. I edited it. Here is the exact message:        Error: File hello.py; Line 3:
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Does the error remain if you change input() to raw_input()?

Comment: The error does remain, but I have discovered the problem. I was using TextWrangler, and I think the first commenter is correct that it probably does not support "input", because I found the official Python software (version 3.5), installed it, pasted the exact same code into it and it works fine. So I guess TextWrangler is not the best option to use for writing Python programs. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: It's not as simple as choosing **#! > Run** from the BBEdit menu, but you can continue to use BBEdit with Pyton's `input()`:  just command-tab to Terminal, `cd` to the proper directory, and run the script there like this `python3 program.py`

Comment: Nothing to say for your issue.  You need to debug the code with **traceback** modules.